# Why can I ignore white space using 'svn merge -x -w' but not 'svn update' and how do I get around it?

Tags: svn

'svn merge' supports the '-x -w' option that tells the internal 3-way diff implementation to ignore conflicts due only to white space. This is true regardless if the conflict is in a checked in revision or a modified working copy that is target of the merge.

Thus, I would expect the same to be true for 'svn update' in the case where I am updating a modified working copy and there are incoming changes that create conflicts due only to white space. Unfortunately, 'svn update' does not support the '-x -w' option and I am forced to manually resolve. In a big project, this can be a real hassle.

Seems to me, both situations are the same and if the internal 3-way diff supports ignoring conflicts due to white space in once case, it should be able to do so in the other.

Can anyone explain why svn does not support '-x -w' for svn update?
Can anyone offer a solution that allows me to get around this limitation?

Thanks!

svn up -x -w ...
Subcommand 'update' doesn't accept option '-x [--extensions] ARG'
Type 'svn help update' for usage.